Which security policy disables "when should Windows require you to sign in again"?
In Windows 11 Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options there's the option:

If you've been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again?

This setting is dimmed  with the message:

Security policies on this PC are preventing some options from being shown

Which security policy is it referring to?
Windows is joined to a domain, but gpreport doesn't list any policies that seems to affect this setting.
The user account is set up with Windows Hello.

This is the related policy:
Administrative Templates -> System -> Power Management -> Sleep Settings -> Require a password when a computer wakes
The corresponding registry value is:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\0e796bdb-100d-47d6-a2d5-f7d2daa51f51\ACIndex (or DCIndex depending on which one is set)

The policy is set to "Not configured". It does not appear to be set from a domain policy. The registry value does not exist. So, should I create the registry value? Should I set the policy to something other than "not configured" ?
